# CiviCRM and Docker

Tags: developer

Are any of the CiviCRM core team using docker? and is there a preferred installation?

I note there are a few drupal docker projects, such as [this](https://github.com/ricardoamaro/docker-drupal) but couldn't see anything for Civi.

Comment: This came up during CiviCon this week - someone mentioned they're using CiviCRM with Docker during the DevOps BoF.  They said there are some quirks but it works, and they'll share the quirks.  I don't want to put their (or my) personal info on here - but if you message me through the forums (PalanteJon) I can put you in touch with that person.

Comment: hey thanks Jon - do you think it would be better if you pinged them and invited them to share their insights here?

Comment: @ErickBShulz sure - but I don't want to share their name here. Ping me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[PTP](http://progressivetech.org) has been experimenting with docker for a few months and is planning to use it in production soon (to replace our aegir provisioning system). I've just been working today on finishing a [Docker file for setting up a civicrm-buildkit instance.](https://github.com/progressivetech/docker-civicrm-buildkit). Feedback welcome!

Comment: How's Docker in production coming along?

Answer (score 7):

No one on the core team is actively using docker, although a few of us experiment with it.

Several of us do use the [civibuild](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit/blob/master/doc/civibuild.md) command from https://buildkit.civicrm.org/ . It defines the reference/demo builds used by http://d46.demo.civicrm.org , http://wp46.demo.civicrm.org , etal.

Civibuild tackles a slightly different part of the stack than Docker or Vagrant. Where Docker and Vagrant generate a system-image (complete with Linux distro, binaries, and PHP/JS code), civibuild is only the portable part which installs the PHP/JS app. Civibuild could be used within a Vagrant/Docker/EC2/OpenStack system.  Ideally, it would be great to have a http://packer.io/ setup with civibuild.

Answer (score 3):

I have put together a CiviCRM-buildkit-based Docker image myself, and I would appreciate help and feedback with testing. It's quite configurable as you can choose any buildkit-based build script, and it includes SSMTP support for sending emails.

The primary advantage here is that it adheres to the Docker principals and philosophy. It is minimal, only including what the buildkit environment needs. It doesn't require the user to preconfigure their Docker build environment, which many Docker hosts don't give you access to, it doesn't use baseimage, and it doesn't bundle it's own SSH server.

https://github.com/djcf/civibuild-docker

Answer (score 0):

I could never quite get the existing CiviCRM container to work right so I decided to build from scratch. It takes the basic Drupal Container (with PHP 7.4 and MariaDB) then adds all the updates and the latest versions.

You can get the scripts and instructions here: https://github.com/jdgamsterdam/civicrmdocker